# Json formatting - using Stringify

Tags: php, json, stringify

I am having some trouble with JSON's stringify function. Reading from a form and using,

```
var obj = $.map(inputs, function(n, i)
{
    var o = {};
    o[n.name] = $(n).val();
    return o;
});

data = JSON.stringify(obj);
```

**I get**

```
[{"offer_type":""},{"property_name":""},{"room_type":""},{"rent":""},{"deposit":""},{"building_type":""},{"property_type":""},{"budget":""},{"locality":"All"}]
```

while the php needs this,

```
[{"offer_type":"BUY","property_name": null,"locality": "kodihalli","property_type":"Apartment","room_type":null,"rent":null,"deposit":null,"building_type":null}]
```

notice the '{}' after each value, which i don't need.

**Can i do something with Stringify to change the format?**

Answer (score 0):

Stringify is fine. The object you create is not the same object that you want. This should make it better:

```
var obj = {};
$.each(inputs, function(n, i) {
    o[n.name] = $(n).val();
});
obj = [obj];
```

Comment: i see your point, i am doing something wrong with the braces code.

Comment: I tried your code, doesnt seem to work, can we have obj = {}, how will the next line code relate

Comment: Ah, I see - you are wrapping it in an array that I didn't notice. Just add `obj = [obj]` at the end. (edited in)

Comment: If you really need that format then you can use replace method. Just replace all {} and [] , Then just add [{ and }] .

Comment: I was finally able to achieve this! I used a replace and added the quotes back in. Thanks Manish and Amadan